# How to convert a elevated command prompt to a regular command prompt?

Tags: windows, permissions, uac, command-line-interface, user-permissions

I have UAC disabled on my system, and all command prompts start as elevated ("Administrator: ..."). Even if I start cmd.exe from the Start Menu, it's still elevated.

Is there a way to run a non-elevated command prompt somehow?

I need that so that I can fix a bug in some software which doesn't work properly unless running as admin.

Comment: This works: `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 <program>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sysinternals to the rescue! There is an option added some time ago to run a command as a limited user.

```
    Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file][-u user [-p psswd]][-n s][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,... ] cmd [arguments]


-d  Don't wait for application to terminate. Only use this option for non-interactive applications.
-e  Does not load the specified account's profile.
-f  Copy the specified program to the remote system even if the file already exists on the remote system.
-i  Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.
-l  Run process as limited user (strips the Administrators group and allows only privileges assigned to the Users group). On Windows Vista the process runs with Low Integrity.
```

Specifically I'm recommending running

```
psexec -i -d -l "your command here"
```

This will run the command interactively, (so you can see the results) detached, (so the command line returns immediately -- not strictly necessary), and as a limited user.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove your username from the administrator group on the computer, or create another account without admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will run the program without elevation nor as a limited user.  In other words, the integrity level will be medium instead of high or low.

```
psexec -u %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% -p password command arguments
```

Adding -l will run the program as a limited user (i.e. integrity level low).

Comment: good but how to avoid the use of password?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot "unelevate" a process.

If you start cmd.exe from another application (a non-elevated one), it shouldn't start as admin.